# fast way for finding GUIDs

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I have lots(+2000) of GUIDs(in some network class) and my program must find one of them when it receives a message and do the job associated with it.
the positive point is i have a hard-code generator, but the fastest way is my goal(and i don't know how to implement it).

my code should do something like this:

```
switch(received guid)  
{  
case guid1: do job 1; break;  
case guid2: do job 2; break;  
case guid3: do job 3; break;  
case guid4: do job 4; break;  
....  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "must find one of them" ? How do you intend to find the GUID from the message ? Is that the point of your question ?

Comment: @Seb:no, i have the guid delivered with the message, but i must find the equal guid in my list(there is no actual list).

Comment: currently, i have three answers from delegate(slowest thing in the world) lovers.

Comment: Delegates aren't that slow, but in all cases when it comes to performance, profiling is the only sure way to know which solution is fastest.

Comment: Are you sure that 2000+ comparisons would be quicker than a hashtable lookup and delegate invocation?  Your current approach is O(n) (on average n/2) with the worst case for the last entry.  A hashtable lookup would be near constant time O(1) and the delegate invocation would be constant too.

Comment: @Paul Ruane:delegates do boxing and unboxing and i have 3-20 parameters for every job.

Comment: BTW, how many messages are you processing at a time?  If each guid is sent in its own network call the bottle neck will most likely be in the connection and not the delegate lookup and invoke.

Comment: @behrooz: What do you mean delegates do boxing and unboxing?

Comment: they get parameters as object[] ; use reflector to see it yourself.

Comment: @behrooz: Given this code: `Action<string, int> action = (s, i) => Console.WriteLine(s.Length > i); action("hello world", 42);` I don't see any boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Brian:protected virtual object DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args)
{
    RuntimeMethodHandle methodHandle = new RuntimeMethodHandle(this.GetInvokeMethod());
    RuntimeMethodInfo methodBase = (RuntimeMethodInfo) RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(Type.GetTypeHandle(this), methodHandle);
    return methodBase.Invoke(this, BindingFlags.Default, null, args, null, true);
}

Comment: @Behrooz: That's right, but that only applies to dynamic invocation of the delegate. The code in my example calls Invoke directly on the delegate and this is strongly typed.

Comment: but that is the only invoke method i could find with reflector,Im sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Matthew Whited:sorry i read your comment right now, I am using RUDP.

Comment: @Behoorz: That is a streamlined protocol but you are still building a packet to send across the wire.  It is still likely that you bottle neck will be latency or I/O more then cycles and lookup time.  Are the Guids required?  Could you replace then with something like an Enumeration or int/uint?

Comment: @Matthew Whited:unfortunately i cannot because i am working with tables and the guids may refer to tables or their columns and it can be really hard to generate/maintance code if i use int/uint.

Comment: @Matthew Whited:i don't think that bottle neck is I/O because it can receive 10000 messages/seconds and if i have 1GHZ of cpu(it is always less than this because my customers use old machines) for network, then i can only have 100M Cycles for each message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an interface for doing the Job, then implement 2000 classes which do the work, each of which knows its own guid.  Then add the classes to a dictionary using its guid as the key.  Then when you get the guid, you look the object up in the dictionary and call the method on the interface.

```
public interface IJobDoer
{
    void DoJob();
    Guid Guid{get;}
}

public class FirstJobType : IJobDoer
{
    void DoJob()
    {
     /// whatever...
    }
    Guid Guid { get{return "insert-guid-here";}}
}
```

Comment: nice idea, i am going to implement it.(it does less boxing/unboxing than delegate)

Comment: the thing I like about this is that it gives you good separation of concerns as each class only has the code for the job it is responsible for.

Comment: Am I really the only person that sees maintaining 2000 classes being a problem? How is this even a remotely suitable solution?

Comment: i said that i have a hard-code generator.and it solves everything.

Comment: @Programming Hero:  you have to manage the 2000 'job handlers' some way.  would managing 2000 delegates be any easier.  I would have thought that having the classes divided up into some appropriate namespaces would help, but basically you are going to have to manage them somehow and having each one in its own class, with the functionality all in one place seems as good a solution as any to me.

Comment: @Behrooz: Why would delegates have anything to do with Boxing/Unboxing?

Answer (score 15):

You could create a Dictionary with the Guid as the key and a delegate reference as the value. That would ensure fast lookups.

Comment: Isn't a dictionary exactly what switch would build under the covers anyway? :p

Comment: @Randolpho: That depends on the compiler. But the problem is C# only allows switch on integral types and strings.

Comment: @Randolpho: Yes, in certain circumstances, the C# compiler might generate code that fills a static dictionary and uses this. In other scenario's it just generates a big list of if else statements. Still, there's a big difference between writing an big unmaintainable switch and using a dictionary, no matter what the compiler generates under the covers.

Comment: @Steven: ok, I agree. I was just pointing it out. :) @Brian Rasmussen: very true. I figured anyone who switched on a Guid would switch on its hashcode or string value.

Answer (score 6):

Use a hashtable which maps Guid to a delegate or a class that represents the task, such as `Dictionary<Guid, Action>` or `Dictionary<Guid, Task>`.

Comment: I think that's the sane way to do what he wants.

Answer (score 4):

A `Dictionary<Guid, JobDelegate>` would probably be faster than a switch statement.

But you would have to profile to be sure.

Comment: I'm not sure about faster... but it would be much nicer to maintain for 2000+ guids.

Comment: @Matthew: the OP mentions a code-generator. I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: True, but just because code is generated doesn't mean it isn't maintained.

Comment: When code is generated, maintenance usually means: re-generate.

Comment: Performance would be about the same, since C# will generate a Dictionary under the covers for big switch blocks. But as Matthew already said, maintainability is most of the time far more important than those few extra milliseconds or probably even microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

I like to show a variation of the dictionary approach others already proposed. Building on this that solution, you could do the following.

1 Define a base class:

```
public abstract class JobDoer
{
    public abstract void DoJob();
}
```

2 Define a attribute for decoration of job doers.

```
public sealed class JobDoerAttribute : Attribute
{
    JobDoerAttribute(string jobDoerId)
    {
        this.JobDoerId = new Guid(jobDoerId);
    }

    public Guid JobDoerId { get; private set; }
}
```

3 Define the actual job doer classes that are decorated with that attribute. For instance:

```
[JobDoer("063EE2B2-3759-11DF-B738-49BB56D89593")]
public sealed class SpecificJobDoer : JobDoer
{
    public override void DoJob()
    {
        // Do a specific job
    }
}
```

4 Define a `JobDoerFactory` that enables retrieving `JobDoer` instances by their Id as it is defined in the attribute:

```
public static class JobDoerFactory
{
    static Dictionary<Guid, JobDoer> cache;

    static JobDoerFactory()
    {
        // Building the cache is slow, but it will only run once 
        // during the lifetime of the AppDomain.
        cache = BuildCache();
    }

    public static JobDoer GetInstanceById(Guid jobDoerId)
    {
        // Retrieving a JobDoer is as fast as using a switch statement.
        return cache[jobDoerId];
    }

    private static Dictionary<Guid, JobDoer> BuildCache()
    {
        // See implementation below.
    }
}
```

In the `BuildCache` method, you can do the loading of `JobDoer` instances by using reflection.

```
private static Dictionary<Guid, JobDoer> BuildCache()
{
    // This is a bit naive implementation; we miss some error checking,
    // but you'll get the idea :-)
    var jobDoers =
       (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from type in assembly.GetTypes()
        where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(JobDoer))
        let attributes =
            type.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JobDoerAttribute), true)
        where attributes.Length > 0
        let attribute = attributes[0] as JobDoerAttribute
        select new { attribute.JobDoerId, type }).ToArray();

    var cache = new Dictionary<Guid, JobDoer>(jobDoers.Length);

    foreach (jobDoer in jobDoers)
    {
        // Note that actually a single instance of the job doer is
        // cached by ID. This means that every Job Doer must be 
        // thread-safe and usable multiple times. If this is not 
        // feasable, you can also create store a set of Func<JobDoer> 
        // objects that enable creating a new instance on each call.
        cache[jobDoer.JobDoerId] =
            (JobDoer)Activator.CreateInstance(jobDoer.type);
    }
    return cache;
}
```

I didn't test this code, so I don't know if it compiles, but I used this mechanism in a project a few years back. This way it is easy to define new classes, without the need to hook it up to some dictionary. It is done automatically at runtime.

This might look a bit like overkill, but if you have +2000 `JobDoer` classes, this could help you a lot.

Update:
Note that if you don't like the idea of the `JobDoerAttribute`, you can also implement it as abstract property on the abstract `JobDoer` class. However, I've found using an attribute makes the code very explicit and expressive.

Comment: Nice flexible approach! Keep in mind that reflection isn't your best friend when it comes to performance, but since it's only performed once and then cached, this might not be such of a problem in this case.

Comment: "but since it's only performed once and then cached". Exactly. Performance of this solution is as good as a `switch` statement, because that's what C# is doing under the covers (creating a dictionary in the static constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dictionary with Guid And Action, and search over it.